# basic definition of cylinder

Tags: geometry

Given a line L and a curve C in a plane P, **the cylinder with generator L and directrix C is the surface obtained by moving L parallel to itself, so that a point of L is always on C**[image]

My doubt:

If the curve C is any closed curve for eg- let it represents a square and the generator line is parallel to fixed line or (say moving parallel to itself )
***Then that solid obtained is cylinder or not?***

Comment: How do **YOU** define a cylinder?

Comment: i am confused with the base of a cylinder by the above definition. can we say that  a cuboid is cylinder..?

Comment: can we say tha the left sided picture represents a cylinder which i have posted/

Comment: Oblique cylinders are well-established, but cylinders with non-circular base are distinctly unusual.

Comment: @almagest cylinders with non circular bases are unusual but can we say that the this types of solids eg: cuboid, cube, curved surfaces with irregular bases etc comes in cylinder family

Comment: @girishkumarchandora It is not a standard usage. You are free to use it if you wish, but you should make your usage clear. Unfortunately, there are many instances in maths where usage has not been standardised. Even when it has, there is nothing to stop you using a different definition, provided you make things clear.

Comment: @almagest see this picture [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GzSX8.gif) can we call it as a cylinder?

Comment: Few people would call it a cylinder. Even "irregular prism" would not command universal support, although it is far more likely to be understood than "cylinder".

Comment: but for irregular prism the above definition of cylinder is satisfied then why we dont call it as cylinder?

Comment: @almagest the rectangular prism, hexagonal prism etc all satisfies the definition the definition of cylinder then why we are not considering as them as a cylinder? please explain i read these definion of cylinder everywhere** a surface generated by a line which is parallel to a fixed line and which fulfills one more condition eg: intersecting a given curve, the it is called as cylinder ** my doubt is we take any two congruent surfaces(regular\irregular) on the top and bottom and then joining the surfaces by parallel lines to one another then ** the obtained surfaces is cylinder or not?**

Comment: Few people do consider them as cylinders! The definition of cylinder you are using is NOT widely accepted.

Comment: @almagest then what is the definition of cylinder according to you . This definition is written in my book and it is also written on the internet etc

Comment: See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_(geometry) The problem is that the word "cylinder" has been around for a long time. Relatively recently various mathematicians may have thought it would be helpful to widen its meaning, but they have not had much success in carrying others with them.

Comment: @almagest i am saying that go to the definition of of cylinder in terms of directrix, locus, generator etc

Comment: @girishkumarchandora This is a pointless debate! All I can tell you is that it is a mistake to use a weird definition of cylinder which most people will misunderstand - unless you clearly flag up what you are doing.

Comment: @almagest i am providing link of the definition which i have wrote [link](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c416.html)